# Failing to create a subdirectory in Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS on Android 10 (Xiaomi MI 9)

Tags: java, android

My customer had an old app with `targetSdkVersion 28`. It creates a folder in a shared location so that the user can access the app's generated files later.

Then the customer requested an upgrade. At first, we updated it to `targetSdkVersion 30`. Of course, our attempt to write files started failing. After some investigation, we found that we have to use a known folder from an enum value instead of storage root. So we decided to use Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS. It worked just fine on Android 11 device, the app was able to create a subfolder and write files there.

Then we tested it on Android 10, and it does not work. `mkdirs()` returns false when trying to create path `/storage/emulated/0/Documents/MySubfolder`. At first, I thought it was caused by the fact that the test device (Xiaomi Mi 9) did not have Documents folder at all, so I created it manually. Still, `mkdirs()` returns false when creating MySubfolder. I also tried to delete Documents folder on the Android 11 device - the app was able to create the full path `/storage/emulated/0/Documents/MySubfolder` without any problems.

What's going on there? Why does creating folders in `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)` work on Android 11 but not on Android 10?

The code follows.

```
public static File getWriteableUserDirPath()
{
    String folderName = "MySubfolder";
    File dir = null;
    
    // at first, try the legacy approach - creating the folder in the shared root
    try {
        dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(folderName);
        dir = tryEnsureSubDirectory(dir);
        if (dir != null)
            return dir; // works on all devices as long as targetSdkVersion <= 28
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        dir = null;
    }

    // the check to keep the compiler happy with Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS not existing before KITKAT
    // but should not really return here - the old approach above should still have worked on KITKAT
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        return dir;

    // if got here, the old way did not work
    // try the new way (which also might be deprecated soon :()
    try {

        dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), folderName);
        dir = tryEnsureSubDirectory(dir);
        if (dir != null)
            return dir; // problem - mkdirs() here works on Android 11 (tested on Nokia 8.1) but not on Android 10 (tested on Xiaomi MI 9)!!! Why so?
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        dir = null;
    }

    return dir;
}

private static File tryEnsureSubDirectory(File dir)
{
    // make sure the path directory exists.
    if (!dir.exists())
    {
        boolean success = dir.mkdirs();
        if (!success)
        {
            dir = null;
        }
    }
    return dir;
}
```

Comment: Add android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" to application tag of manifest file.

Comment: @blackapps  Thanks, that will make the old way work. But won't the new `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)` work on Android 10 ? If DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS exists since KitKat, then why it does not work on Android 10?

Comment: You are mentioning nothing new. And on Android 10 devices you only have read and write acces to external storage using the attribute i told you. Thats all.

Comment: Ok, I was under impression that the new way was supposed to work since KitKat, and with Android 11 it became mandatory. It's strange that on A10 you still cannot use the new way AND you cannot use the old way either without that app tag. That's really strange transition logic from Google.

Comment: New way? Dont understand. You can create as much files and folders in public Documents directory as you want. On A10. And below A10. And above A10. Only for A10 you need my first comment.

Comment: Yes, Google made a mess out of it. It looks they first planned to remove all read and write access to external storage and only allowing them to private directories. When they could not finish it before the next release they quickly introduced that attribute as otherwise nothing would run anymore. A mess indeed.